# How to start an activity in a tab?

Tags: android, tabs

I am using tabs in my application.

I have 3 tabs : home, services, contact us.

In the 'home tab', there is 'login button' and my requirement is when I click the login button, it should display the view for 'login' in the same tab itself. That means it should start another activity (login.class) and display corresponding view (login.xml). And the tabs should be displayed at the top as before.

But when I click the login button, it should start login activity, but the tabs are disappeared.

How can I start an activity in the same tab itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you may need to use `ActivityGroup` (it's pain in the ass I have to say):

[Use Android ActivityGroup within TabHost to show different Activity](http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity)

There are more examples about it, just Google them.

Comment: There's an updated version of the linked solution in http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/android-viewflipper-within-tabhost-for-tabs-with-different-views-and-better-memory

Comment: A new update: https://www.united-coders.com/nico-heid/android-viewflipper-within-tabhost-for-tabs-with-different-views-and-better-memory/

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with the TabHost, because I didn't used it by now, but 
what I found could be interesting for you:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

There they are using

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
              .setContent(intent);
```

So what you can use is calling an Intent on an existing Activity when user logged in
and use

```
public TabHost.TabSpec setContent (Intent intent)
```

This sounds feasible to to me.

Comment: but here we can specify only one activity, i want one more activity within this activity