# Ways to implement always on top tabwidget

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

I have some concerns with how to approach this:

background:
Main app view has a TabHost that displays different activities.
From these activities more activities can be launched that is not part of the TabHost.

What I want to accomplish is to keep the TabWidget on top of these activities that is not part of the TabHost.

One way I'm thinking is to have these new activities' layout contain a TabWidget made to look the same as the real thing. But it feels hacky and view switching animation may be complicated.

Another one is to tap into the LocalActivityManager in the TabHost and launch the activities using it, and add the view from the returned Window to the TabHost's tabcontent.

Any suggestions welcome!
Thanks.

Comment: Actually going to change my activities into fragments and implement solution posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually found solutions to this with fragments and without.

with fragments:
[Design Application with fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538779/design-application-with-fragments)

without fragments:
basically this UI style fits nicely with fragments, otherwise you have to roll your own ActivityGroup to manage the multiple activities.
[How to start an activity in a tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594256/how-to-start-an-activity-in-a-tab)